# XSL-FO: Need to disable page break at page sequence level

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

My requirement is to produce, essentially, a page WITHIN a page. The xsl defines a page 1/3 the size of an A4 sheet, but up to 3 of them must print on the sheet. The page is a standard header/body/footer, with a 'Page X of Y' on it and of course it is simple. But if there are 4 of these "pages", only 2 pages should be printed, 3 on the first and 1 on the second. But 4 pages are printed, because the output PDF "tells" the printer that is a complete sheet. So what I want to do is either:

- code the fo so it does not page break after it finished a page (something like `page-break-after="avoid"` but at the page sequence level)
  OR
- generate a page sequence within a page sequence, the outer one being defined as A4 size, the inner 1/3 of that.

I've tried the 2nd directly in a simple way, i.e.,

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-third_A4">
    ...  
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

..and the processor definitely does NOT like it.

Are there any instructions I can apply that could do either of these? I looked in places like schemacentral and w3schools.com and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you needs (a drawing would help), but can't you simply put your content into a series of `fo:block-container` elements with specified height? They would come out stacked vertically.

If you need more complex geometry, check out [flow-maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_flow-map) feature of XSL 1.1. Three body regions per page connected sequentially in a `<fo:flow-target-list>`, and a single `fo:flow` providing content for them.

Having `fo:page-sequence` within another `fo:page-sequence` is not valid according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_page-sequence) (what would a page number mean then?), and every `fo:page-sequence` starts a new physical page by definition.

[fo:page-sequence-wrapper](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_page-sequence-wrapper) won't help you on sub-page level either.